# What's the difference between CloudQueueClient & QueueClient classes in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage-queues

For interacting with Azure queue storage .NET provides the CloudQueueClient  & QueueClient classes. They can be found via the below links.

- [CloudQueueClient MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueueclient?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)
- [QueueClient MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-legacy)

When referring the above documentations I noticed that CloudQueueClient comes from the Legacy version of Azure SDK for .NET & QueueClient comes from the latest version of Azure SDK for .NET.

Great if someone could explain the exact difference & use cases of these two classes.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that CloudQueueClient comes from the Legacy version of Azure SDK for .NET & QueueClient comes from the latest version of Azure SDK for .NET.

Well, there it is! They have the same purposes but a different name. Several SDKs have seen newer versions in which names and other things have changed to better align the SDK to the [same (new) principles](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/general_introduction.html) so the developer experience is the same between all SDKs.

The different V12 and up packages are listened [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage#libraries-for-data-access). There is no clear migration guide but new sample are [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-quickstart-queues-dotnet?tabs=environment-variable-windows)